# Importing email to Thunderbird

Tags: thunderbird

How do I configure Gmail and Hotmail such that all folders appear in Thunderbird and are populated?
I tried to migrate and only the Inbox and Trash folders appear in Thunderbird.

Answer (score 1):

To access all folders on the server, you will need to add Gmail as an **IMAP** account, instead of POP. (Note that the translation of Gmail's labels to regular folders is a little confusing.)

For Gmail, the settings are autodetected; just choose IMAP when asked. For Outlook.com, the same should work but [here's manual configuration](https://support.mozillamessaging.com/en-US/kb/thunderbird-and-hotmail) just in case.